# Loading a CSV file into Azure Table using the file name

Tags: alteryx

I am trying to insert records from ~2000 CSV files into an Azure Database  into 700 tables. Each file is named as "TABLENAME FileCount" i.e. (TableName1 01, TableName1 02,TableName5 09,TableName5 10 ..TaleName FileCount)
I want to know how to use Alteryx to load the CSV files into Azure with the following steps 
1) Figure out table name from the file - how to use the LEFT and LEN Functions? 
2) Load the file into an Azure DB where the tables are already created

Using Alteryx is mandatory. I can easily do this with PHP or even microsoft excel to generate bulk insert queries but do not want to consider these tools at present.

In Alteryx, I have used an input tool and specified CSV as an input. I have also checked the option to include file names as a separate column. I am unable to ascertain the next steps on the Alteryx interface i.e which tool to use to connect to Azure db and specify the file name as the table name.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of using LEFT, LENGTH etc, that will be the formula tool. Some other formula's that may come in handy are FINDSTRING and TRIM

You can use the Output tool to write to an Azure DB and select "Take File or table name from field" at the bottom of the config window.